# PowerShell in batch : unexpected directory creation using a FOR loop and Tmp variable :-O

Tags: batch-file, powershell-5.1

I have to upgrade an existing batch script, for a new need. This one is launching PowerShell subscripts. I found an unexpected behaviour, that I can reproduce on a smaller use case.

Create a "test" directory
Inside, create 2 directories "1" and "2"
In directory "1", create 2 empty files, "1.txt" and "2.txt"
In directory "2", create 2 empty files, "3.txt" and "4.txt"
In "test", create text.bat with the following code:

```
@echo OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

REM go to directory "1" and get file names into files.txt
chdir 1
PowerShell "Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File -FilePath files.txt -Encoding ASCII"
    
REM loop over file names and print them
for /F "usebackq tokens=* " %%b in ("files.txt") do (       

    REM set a variable to each file name and print it
    set Tmp=%%b
    echo !Tmp!
)

REM go to directory "2" and get file names into files.txt
chdir ..
chdir 2

pause

REM At this stage, nothing strange in folder "2"

PowerShell "Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File -FilePath files2.txt -Encoding ASCII"

REM At this stage, in directory "2", files2.txt is created correctly. BUT a unexpected DIRECTORY has been created, which name if the one of the last looped file in directory "1" (in that case, "files.txt")

pause
```

When running the batch, files.txt and files2.txt are created into "1" and "2", as expected.
The files of "1" are printed out as expected.
BUT right after the second Powershell script, a folder, named "files.txt" is created into folder "2".
I made some test with other names for the Tmp variable, and oddly the pb does not appear with a variable named differently ("Tmp2" for example)

Can someone explain this strange behaviour ?

I'm on Windows 10, with
PSVersion                      5.1.19041.4046
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.4046
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

Comment: Please don't use the name `Tmp` for a variable, there is already an environment variable using that name.

Comment: Why are you using Powershell for something a batch file can easily do?

Answer (score 2):

The **user** environment variables `TEMP` and `TMP` are defined by Windows default with the path of the directory for temporary files. Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) window and run `set TEMP` and `set TMP` to see them with their values. Run just `set` to see all environment variables defined by default for the current user account and see also [Windows environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Windows).

Run in the command prompt window `reg QUERY HKCU\Environment` and their is output most likely at least:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
    TEMP    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
    TMP    REG_EXPAND_SZ    %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp
```

The command line `set Tmp=%%b` in the batch file redefines in the **FOR** loop the **local** environment variable `TMP` with the name of the current file read from the file `files.txt` which is on last loop run the string `files.txt`.

**That is the source of the problem. The redefinition of the environment variable `TMP` holding per definition the full path to the directory for temporary files with the string `files.txt` is no good idea.**

There can be viewed with the free Windows Sysinternals (Microsoft) tool [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) all the registry and file system accesses done by `powershell.exe` on being run by `cmd.exe` a second time.

I recommend to change the command line

```
PowerShell "Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File -FilePath files2.txt -Encoding ASCII"
```

in the batch file to just

```
PowerShell "echo hello"
```

That makes it easier to see in log of *Process Monitor* what happens in the background.

Or there is used following single line batch file for reproducing the issue:

```
@setlocal & set "TMP=files.txt" & %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe "echo hello" & endlocal
```

Recommended filters set in *Process Monitor* in addition to the defaults:

| **Column** | **Relation** | **Value** | **Action** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Process Name | is | cmd.exe | Include |
| Process Name | is | powershell.exe | Include |

*PowerShell* wants to create a small script file `__PSScriptPolicyTest_*.*.ps1` in the directory for temporary files of which directory path is assigned to the environment variable `TMP`. That should be the directory `files.txt` in the current working directory after the last redefinition of the environment variable `TMP` in the **FOR** loop respectively as second command in the single line batch file. The directory `files.txt` does currently not exist in the current directory. But that is no problem for *PowerShell* as it creates now successfully the directory `files.txt`.

Then the script file `__PSScriptPolicyTest_*.*.ps1` is created in the temporary files directory `files.txt` in the current working directory.

It can be seen with *Process Monitor* that each execution of *PowerShell* causes lots of registry and file system accesses before even a simple PS command like `echo hello` is executed.

I recommend reading also [What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41461002/3074564) The environment variable is here `TMP` and not `PATH` but `cmd.exe` calls the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) for execution of `powershell.exe` with a null pointer for the function parameter `lpEnvironment`. The Windows kernel function `CreateProcess` makes therefore a copy of the current environment variables list of process `cmd.exe` with the redefined `TMP` variable for process `powershell.exe` and standard actions of *PowerShell* are done now with wrong temporary files directory.